# Is there any Graphical Control Panel available for apache2 and MySQL to start and stop them?

Tags: programming

I dont like command line. Is there a Graphical Control Panel to start/stop apache2 ? and MySQL ?

Comment: if u got a solution please mark it as answered by ticking the arron next the the answer that answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try "Bootup-Manager", package name 'bum'. It's similar to the Services Manager for Windows. You can start and stop both MySQL and Apache from there. Click 'Advanced' and go to the services tab.

If I were you, I would create short and simple scripts to start and stop the services instead, then just add launchers for the scripts to your application launcher.

Comment: Bootup Manager is the easiest way to start/stop any service from starting automatically. Its similar to "msconfig" on Windows

Answer (score 2):

**LAMP Quicklist**

[image]

1.Open a new file:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/lamp.desktop
```

2. Copy the text below

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=LAMP
GenericName=LAMP
X-GNOME-FullName=LAMP
Comment=Open services of your LAMP server
Exec=gksu service apache2 start && gksu service mysql start
Icon=emblem-web
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Start;Stop;Restart


[Start Shortcut Group]
Name=Start
Exec=gksu service apache2 start && gksu service mysql start
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Stop Shortcut Group]
Name=Stop
Exec=gksu service apache2 stop && gksu service mysql stop
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Restart Shortcut Group]
Name=Restart
Exec=gksu service apache2 restart && gksu service mysql restart
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

3.Drag and Drop onto the launcher by navigating to ~/.local/share/applications/ in Nautilus. [or you can simply drag drop by searching LAMP in the dash]

Comment: Will it work on Ubuntu 11.10 ? Im still using 11.10. Your screenshot looks like you are on Ub 12.04

Comment: yes it will work try it! i used it when i had 11.10

Answer (score 1):

**have a look at webmin**

If you are using the DEB version of webmin, first download the file from the downloads page , or run the command :

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.580_all.deb
```

then run the command :

```
dpkg --install webmin_1.580_all.deb
```

The install will be done automatically to /usr/share/webmin, the administration username set to root and the password to your current root password. You should now be able to login to Webmin at the URL https://localhost:10000/. Or if accessing it remotely, replace localhost with your system's IP address. [Make sure u prefix https and not http]

If Debian complains about missing dependencies, you can install them with the command :

```
sudo apt-get install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime libio-pty-perl apt-show-versions python
```

If you are installing on Ubuntu and the apt-get command reports that some of the packages cannot be found, edit /etc/apt/sources.list and make sure the lines ending with universe are not commented out.

Comment: Is there something simpler ? This has lot of menus and options.

Comment: this IMO is simplest
or u can create a script and then create a desktop shortcut in ~./.local/share/applications

Comment: i meant IMO= in my opinion sorry check my new answer that i submitted, i guess thats what u looking for!!!
http://askubuntu.com/a/134999/27027

Answer (score -1):

This is more of a remote control panel but it might work for your needs. It currently only states that it supports CentOS, Red Hat, and Fedora.

http://www.oakwoodsystems.net/uncategorized/restarting-linux-services-remote-manager/

Comment: "only states that it supports CentOS, Red Hat, and Fedora", no Ubuntu :(